# CSS fails when passing a list to render(request)

Tags: python, css, django

I am trying to follow a tutorial online and for some reason I cannot get css to work correctly with my views.py file and `django 2.2`.  when I remove the "My_context" from `return render(request, 'blog/home.html', My_context)`
and pass something else like
`return render(request, 'blog/home.html', {'title': 'blah')` it seems to work just fine.

I have tried restarting the server and and clearing the page cache.  I am new to `django` and not sure what else to try.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
posts = [
    {
       'author': 'xxxxx',
       'title': 'Blog Post 1',
       'Content': 'My First Post Content',
       'date_posted': 'August 27, 2019'
    },
     {
       'author': 'xxxxx',
       'title': 'Blog Post 2',
       'Content': 'My Second Post Content',
       'date_posted': 'August 27, 2019'
    }
]

# This function fails to load css correctly
def home(request):
    My_context = {
        'posts': posts
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', My_context)

#This function works fine
def about(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/about.html', {'title': 'About'})
```

**home.html**

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %} 
{% block content %} 
{% for post in posts %}
<h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
<p>By {{ post.author }} on {{ post.date_posted }}</p>
<p>{{ post.Content }}</p>
{% endfor %} 
{% endblock content %}
```

**about.html**

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %} 
{% block content %}
<h1>About Page</h1>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major difference between `home()` and `about()` is the template you use.

So you should check your `home.html` contains the path to your css file.

You can also check your console for any error message and share it with us.

Comment: Both about and home are extending from the same base.html.  I don't get an error when loading either of them but the console gives   "[27/Apr/2019 13:57:03] "GET /about/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3226
[27/Apr/2019 13:57:03] "GET /static/blog/main.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0" when loading about and "[27/Apr/2019 13:58:49] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3314" when loading the home page

Comment: I solved the problem it was an error with the '{% if title %} in the base.html file which is why the second function worked and the first did not.  The second function was using the {% else %} portion of the statement.